# Pandas pivot table fixing value columns

Tags: python, pandas

I get a dataframe like below daily,

```
  type  subtype  count
0    A        1     25
1    A        2     36
2    B        1     12
3    B        2     10
4    C        1     40
```

I pivot it and write in db among otherthings,

```
newdf = df.pivot_table('count', 'type', 'subtype',fill_value=0)
newdf
subtype   1   2
type           
A        25  36
B        12  10
C        40   0
```

In a day if data dont have `subtype 2 at all`,

```
  type  subtype  count
0    A        1     25
1    B        1     12
2    C        1     40
```

Then my pivot will fail I mean invalid,

```
df.pivot_table('count', 'type', 'subtype',fill_value=0)
subtype   1
type       
A        25
B        12
C        40
```

currently I'm using this horrible way to take care of that,

```
if 1 not in newdf.columns:
    newdf[1] = 0
elif 2 not in newdf.columns:
    newdf[2] = 0

subtype   1  2
type          
A        25  0
B        12  0
C        40  0
```

This is toy data I have 131 columns. `mylistofsubtypes - df.coulumns` and treverse to add columns with 0 is my current way.

so, any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: your question is not clear. In case of the dataframe with only 1 as subtype, how do you know that the universe of subtypes is {1,2} ?? why not {1,2,3} pr {1,2,4} ?

Comment: I know it is going to be minimum [1,2] for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you couldn't get your expected dataframe directly from `pivot_table` you'll need to add your column manually. But you could do it with for loop instead of manually:

```
list_to_fill = [2,'else']
for col_name in list_to_fill:
    if col_name not in new_df.columns:
        new_df[col_name] = 0

In [252]: new_df
Out[252]:
subtype   1  2  else
type
A        25  0     0
B        12  0     0
C        40  0     0
```

Comment: More or less I'm doing the the same :(

Comment: `pivot_table` doesn't know about any other non-existing values, so how are you expecting it to work then?

Comment: I guess in that case I would not use pivot table for this. Thanks.